# activiti-7 setup *** No rule to make target `activiti-cloud-audit'

Tags: cloud, activiti

am following steps as per https://activiti.gitbook.io/activiti-7-developers-guide on mac OS.

at the make application step, its failing

make[1]: *** No rule to make target `activiti-cloud-audit'.  Stop.
make: *** [application] Error 2

```
    make application

make nginx/up
docker-compose up -d nginx
Starting nginx ... done
make keycloak/up
docker-compose up -d keycloak
nginx is up-to-date
Starting keycloak ... done


Keycloak path 192.168.1.250/auth

make rabbitmq/up
docker-compose up -d rabbitmq
Starting rabbitmq ... done
make example-runtime-bundle example-cloud-connector activiti-cloud-query activiti-cloud-audit activiti-cloud-notifications-graphql 
make example-runtime-bundle/up
docker-compose up -d example-runtime-bundle
rabbitmq is up-to-date
Starting docker-compose_activiti-postgres_1 ... 
nginx is up-to-date
Starting docker-compose_activiti-postgres_1 ... done
Starting example-runtime-bundle             ... done
make example-cloud-connector/up
docker-compose up -d example-cloud-connector
rabbitmq is up-to-date
nginx is up-to-date
keycloak is up-to-date
Starting example-cloud-connector ... done
make activiti-cloud-query/up
docker-compose up -d activiti-cloud-query
rabbitmq is up-to-date
nginx is up-to-date
docker-compose_activiti-postgres_1 is up-to-date
keycloak is up-to-date
Starting activiti-cloud-query ... done
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `activiti-cloud-audit'.  Stop.
make: *** [application] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
activiti-cloud-audit:
container_name: activiti-cloud-activiti
image: activiti/activiti-cloud-audit:${VERSION}
external_links:
  - activiti-cloud-sso-idm
  - activiti-cloud-registry
  - rabbitmq
environment:
  - ACT_AUDIT_PORT=8181
  - JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx128m -Xms128m
  - ACT_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_ENABLED=false
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution to the community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who may not be familiar with the syntax. Further, it can help reduce the need for follow-up questions. Would you mind updating your comment with additional details?